# ListView Android

Tags: android, listview

Добрый день.
Подскажите пожалуйста, как разукрасить ListView? Т.е, к примеру, сделать его как в приложении Вконтакте.

Конкретнее для каждой записи должна быть 'рамочка'.
что-то типо этого [картинка](http://s3.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2013/10/6f08aa38095a7d91718e7478fe7f538b.jpg)

Comment: конкретнее пожалуйста.
Что сделали, что пытались, что не получилось?

Comment: В приложении вконтакте, скорее всего, используется [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html?hl=ru)

Answer (score 1):

Учитесь пользоваться гуглом. ИМХО это **самое** важное умение хорошего программиста, ибо дает возможность использовать чужой опыт.  
[вот это](http://habrahabr.ru/post/133575/) я нашел по запросу [android  custom listview item](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=android+listview+item+custom&oq=android+listview+item+custom&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l5.22347j0&sourceid=chrome&espvd=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&q=android++custom+listview+item&safe=off)